# get vf page to open up in parent window?

Tags: apex, visualforce, html

I have a vf page that is a custom button. That's it.  this VF page is on a STD Page Layout. When the user clicks on the VF page, the parent window needs to be redirected to the new URL.

The way this is working, is that the new page is opening in the vf section of the page layout.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity"  standardStylesheets="true" extensions="OpportunityController" >
<base target="_parent" />
<body style="background:#f3f3ec" >
<apex:form >
<center>

<apex:commandButton action="{!redirect}"  value="Change Record Type" rendered="{!render}"/>
</center>
  </apex:form>
   </body>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice apex VF elements like `<apex:commandLink>` have the attribute `target` where you can specifiy "_top", "_parent", etc.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandLink.htm

> The name of the frame where the resource retrieved by this command
>   link should be displayed. Possible values for this attribute include
>   "_blank", "_parent", "_self", and "_top". You can also specify your
>   own target names by assigning a value to the name attribute of a
>   desired destination.

---

But you are using `<apex:commandButton>` which isn't so nice.

I found this post:  [Command Button Target Attribute](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/CommandButton-target-attribute/m-p/192075#M25662)

**Solution:**

> ```
> <apex:commandButton action="{!saveRecord}" reRender="newWindow" onComplete="openWindow()" />
>
> <script>
>     function openWindow(){
>         window.open("{!$System.Page.newPage}");
>     }
> </script>
> ```

Essentially, create a Javascript function that opens the new page in the desired way and call that function in the `onComplete` attribute of your `<apex:commandButton>`.  I'm not sure if `{!System.Page.newPage}` works so easily, but you can always create the desired `pageReference` in your controller and call the variable in the JS.

Example:

```
public class myController{

    private pageReference desiredPageRef;    

    // code to set a value to desiredPageRef

    public string getDesiredURL(){
        return desiredPageRef.getUrl(); 
    }//END getDesiredURL

}//END class
```

And in your JS:

```
<script>
    function openWindow(){
        window.open("{!DesiredURL}");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Great solution, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the way to accomplish this is use a little javascript which references `top`:

`window.top.location.href = 'http://myredirect.com';`

However, I don't think this works in Salesforce because Visualforce Pages have a different domain than standard pages, which causes this technique to not work.

I think without making the standard page a visualforce page, you can't make this work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might be looking at this later, you can also add a target to the apex:form tag. I used  and it worked. One caveat: I could not get the header and sidebar to appear on the page to which it redirected (in spite of using showheader="true" and sidebar="true" in the apex:page tag of my VF page).